# Can't open file properly in C++

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to read each line from a .geom file and save that in a string.
The user shall input the correct (absolute) filepath and then, until now, should get the content of the .geom file printed out on the console.
The problem is that under every circumstance it seems impossible to open the file via my c++ program.
Everytime I check if the file is opened via `is_open()` it responds with false.
The program, my IDE and the .geom file are all on the same drive and i am currently using windows. The IDE im using is Codeblocks and the executable is build in it.

This is my complete code until now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//a function to check if the given file has the .geom extension
bool isGeom(string file){
  if(file.substr(file.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "geom") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

//main func
int main()
{
    string filepath, geomInput, line;

    cout << "----- GeomView2obj -----" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a valid file path to a .geom file to convert it to an .obj file: \n" << endl;
    //get file path by user
    getline(cin, filepath);

    //declare stream and open file if possible
    ifstream geomFile (filepath.c_str());

    if(!geomFile.is_open()){
        cout << "\nERR: The given file path is invalid or the file does not exist!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if(!isGeom(filepath)){
        cout << "\nERR: The given file is not a .geom file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    //read chars from geom file
    while(getline(geomFile, line)){
        geomInput.append(line + "\n");
    }

    //print string --- DELETE
    cout << geomInput;

    geomFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to first declare my ifstream and then opening the file. 
I also turned the user input off and entered an absolute path where every folder was seperated with two backslashes `\\` instead of one.
I also copied the file to the folder the compiled program lies in and giving the program a relative path to the file as an input, but that also did not help.

Any form of help is much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you put your binary and .geom file in the same directory, then run your binary and enter the filename without any path *from outside your IDE*.  It's likely your problem when running within the IDE is that the IDE is setting some current working directory which doesn't have the .geom file.  It's also possible that you're on Linux, but entering Windows-style backslashes instead of forward slashes for directory separators.

Comment: It's possible the method changed and I'm unaware. But I'm not seeing where you opened the file. Try `ifstream geomFile` then `geomFile.open(filepath)`

Comment: @S.Ramjit `ifstream geomFile (filepath.c_str());` attempts to open the file - nothing wrong with that, though it could be simplified to `if (std::ifstream geomFile{filepath}) { ...use geomFile... } else { ...report error...}`

Comment: @S.Ramjit The `const char*` constructor of `ifstream` takes a filename and opens it. That was always like this.

Comment: @MariusAquarius Have you tried using `std;:filesystem::path` instead of `std::string` as that not only properly type's your variables but also should fix any issues with windows path escapes

Comment: @TonyDelroy putting the file and the binary in the same folder did actually work! Thank you very much for your answer! But how can I encounter such problem when I input absolute filepaths all the time. I am currently using Codeblocks as IDE, can you suggest others?

Comment: [Works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KmwtxFZodsg1UReY). Please provide details, where are all related files (executable, geom file, it path and path you are providing). What are the flags values of `geomFile` when open fails. Also split your code into smaller functions.

Comment: [Full path also works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AWYnH04BJRZFhQ5m).

Comment: @MarekR yeah but it only works if i run the binary outside of my IDE (Codeblocks) for some reason and if the geom file is in the same folder. But it still fails to open the file if i input an absolute path.

Comment: @MarekR it does not seem to work in windows. I entered the right filepath several times and i tried drag and dropping the file to the console, which also does not work.

Comment: @MariusAquarius so edit your question and write it there with more details. What IDE how did you configure it (where executable is build).

Comment: and remove double open as some voted comment points out.

Comment: @MariusAquarius how about printing the filepath in the error message - might help debugging?

Comment: add also `cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno);`

Comment: or `std::perror("Info")` [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p8AyUvPffJocwwoW)

Comment: @MariusAquarius Could you share cmd screen with dir command shown and the absolute filepath that you set as a constant? (without user input)

Comment: @MariusAquarius: I haven't used Codeblocks, so not sure what it could be doing.  If shouldn't screw up absolute filepaths though.  If you're on windows, did you include the drive letter?  Sometimes there can be a unicode character in the actual path that looks a lot like a normal ASCII character that you might have typed when entering the filename.  Separately, for a great editor I recommend CLion, but it's commercial.

Comment: @miszcz137 there is absolutly nothing wrong with the filepaths I entered. When i drag and drop the file to the console there will also be entered the right absolute path to the file. The thing is that the path is working when i run the executable outside of codeblocks.

Comment: also when i print out the entered filepath there is no difference to the input